# modeling correct star schema for ssas tabular

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerpivot, dax, tabular

I'm using ssas tabular (powerpivot) and need to design a data-model and write some DAX.
I have 4 tables in my relational database-model:

Orders(order_id, order_name, order_type)
Spots (spot_id,order_id, spot_name, spot_time, spot_price)
SpotDiscount (spot_id, discount_id, discount_value)
Discounts (discount_id, discount_name)

One order can include multiple spots but one spot (spot_id 1) can only belong to one order.
One spot can include different discounts and every discount have one discount_value.
Ex:
**Order_1** has **spot_1** (*spot_price* 10), **spot_2** (*spot_price* 20)
   **Spot_1** has **discount_name_1**(*discount_value* 10) and **discount_name_2** (*discount_value* 20)
   **Spot_2** has **discount_name_1**(*discount_value* 15) and **discount_name_3** (*discount_value* 30)

I need to write two measures: price(sum) and discount_value(average)

How do I correctly design a star schema with fact table (or maybe two fact tables) so that I in my powerpivot cube can get:

If i choose discount_name_1 I should get 
order_1 with spot_1 and spot_2 and price on order_1 level will have value 50 and discount_value = 12,5 
If I choose discount_name_3 I should get
order_1 with only spot_2 and price on order level = 20 and discount_value = 30

Comment: When building a star schema you make every effort to combine multiple parent - child tables into _one_ fact table as this is much simpler to work with for reporting. When a child table has a metric in it that will be double counted by combining with a parent record, you need to consider if it's practical to represent this in a single fact and either divide it down (so aggregates are correct) or put it in one fact record or put it in its own fact record. I see that @greggyb has just posted a more practical answer along these lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fact(OrderKey, SpotKey, DiscountKey, DateKey, TimeKey Spot_Price, Discount_Value,...)

DimOrder, DimSpot, DimDiscount, etc....

```
TotalPrice:=
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Fact
        ,Fact[OrderKey]
        ,Fact[SpotKey]
        ,Fact[Spot_Price]
    )
    ,Fact[Spot_Price]
)

AverageDiscount:=
AVERAGE(Fact[Discount_Value])
```

Fact table is denormalized and you end up with the simplest star schema you can have.

First measure deserves some explanation. [Spot_Price] is duplicated for any spot with multiple discounts, and we would get wrong results with a simple SUM(). SUMMARIZE() does a group by on all the columns passed to it, following relationships (if necessary, we're looking at a single table here so nothing to follow).

SUMX() iterates over this table and accumulates the value of the expression in its second argument. The SUMMARIZE() has removed our duplicate [Spot_Price]s so we accumulate the unique ones (per unique combination of [OrderKey] and [SpotKey]) in a sum.

Comment: Thx I just did that and it works perfectly! :)
Why do I need to have Fact[Spot_Price] in SUMMARIZE function? As I understand it, it's almost like group by in T-SQL. So I would write it as<br>
SUMMARIZE(
        Fact
        ,Fact[OrderKey]
        ,Fact[SpotKey]
    )

Comment: The granularity of your table is one row per discount. One spot can have multiple discounts, so a simple SUM() would be inappropriate, as it would double count. SUMX() iterates over the table in the first argument. If we don't explicitly include the spot price, it won't be available to accumulate in the SUMX(). We could write an expression instead that would be evaluated for each row in the SUMMARIZE (), but that would be more expensive as we would have a context transition for every row.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot greggyb. I have another challenge in this one. I also have a fact on order level, and it is a fact which cannot be aggregated.. It should only be shown when I use a dimensions from DimOrder table. Should I include it in the same fact table ?

Comment: Yeah, there are several strategies for doing something like that. See the discussion in this forum post, and ask a new question if you need more help.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/676166e9-db09-4966-b4cd-2912df003f9e/show-purchase-in-pivot-table-only-when-local-sales-company-name-is-equal-to-purchase?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7f97475-309b-4ef6-922b-3d0e0a3626bc/force-a-measure-to-be-visible-for-all-rows-in-pivot-table-even-when-there-is-no-data?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel

Answer (score 0):

You say

> One order can include multiple spots but one spot (spot_id 1) can only
>   belong to one order.

That's is not supported in the table definitions you give just above that statement. In the table definitions, one order has only one spot but (unless you've added a unique index to Orders on spot_id) each Spot can have multiple orders. Each Spot can also have multiple discounts.

If you want to have the relationship described in your words, the table definitions should be:

```
Orders(order_id, order_name, order_type)
OrderSpot(order_id, spot_id) -- with a Unique index on spot_id)
Spots (spot_id, spot_name, spot_time, price)
```

or:

```
Orders(order_id, order_name, order_type)
Spots (spot_id, spot_name, spot_time, order_id, price)
```

You can create the ssas cube with Order as the fact table, with one dimention in the Spot Table. If you then add the SpotDiscount and Discount tables with their relations (SpotDiscount to Spot, Discount to SpotDiscount) you have a 1 dimentional.

EDIT as per comments

Well, the Fact table would have order_id, order_name, order_type

The Dimension would be made up of the other 3 tables and have the columns you're interested in: probably spot_name, spot_time, spot_price, discount_name, discount_value.

Comment: Thanx for the answer! 

Sry but I was wrong when I was writing the question. What my relational data-model looks like is just as you wrote<P>
Orders(order_id, order_name, order_type)<br>
Spots (spot_id, spot_name, spot_time, price, order_id)<br>
SpotDiscount (spot_id, discount_id, discount_value)<br>
Discounts (discount_id, discount_name)<p>

So I have a fact table - FactOrders. Which columns do i have in FactOrders table?
And Dimensions are - spots, spotDiscount and Discount? Am I right?